# Error for AspNetCore 2.1 while opening NpgsqlConnection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, ado.net, npgsql

I am facing issue with while opening the NpgsqlConnection in AspNet Core 2.1. It works correctly in AspNet Core 1.1. Following is the error thrown in AspNetCore 2.1

**42501: permission denied to set restricted parameter "transaction_isolation"**

Following is the code snippet

```
    using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(this._configuration["SpringData:ConnectionString"]))
        {
            try
            {   
                ///Error occurs while opening the connection
                dbConnection.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
```

Not sure how to debug it further and resolve it.

**P.S.** Issue started occuring after migrating to AspNetCore 2.1 from AspNetCore1.1

Comment: What is the target database version? Are you trying to connect to Redshift or RDS Postgres?

Comment: Npgsql started setting the transaction isolation mode in 4.0.3, as part of type loading (seeing https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2020). However, I am not aware of any situation where that isn't possible, can you please provide more information on your database (PostgreSQL version, Redshift or what)?

Comment: @ Shay Rojansky, I am using database which is based on Postgres(it is neither RedShift or RDS PostGres. It is proprietary DB based on Postgress but works with Ngpsql). Not sure following information is useful
 SELECT version(); 
 Database version 1.2.5-7571 
 
 SHOW server_version; 
 9.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got resolved after downgrading to Nuget package Npgsql.3.2.7. Earlier it was using Npgsql 4.0.3 which seems to have some issues.

Comment: Why do you assume Npgsql has issues? That error may mean there are missing permissions, or that the target database is an older Postgres version (Redshift comes to mind). Maybe one of the default settings used in 4.0.3 clashes with the old Postgres version

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, Same code works with same database(with same userid) with Npgsql.3.2.7 and does not work with Npgsql 4.0.3. Initially I also thought that it is permission issue. Errror message is misleading. I downgraded the package and it worked without any change in the code

Comment: which doesn't say anything about the package. That's a *Postgres* error saying *your account* doesn't have permission. You get that with Amazon Redshift which is compatible with older Postgres versions. You get that with Amazon RDS Postgres which *doesn't* allow you to modify many settings